# access ubuntu server running in virtualbox from outside network?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

Is it possible to access ubuntu server running in virtualbox from outside network?
I set it up with the bridget network adapter so it has its own IP. I can access my ubuntu server from inside my own network, which is great[(see this link)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237461/how-do-i-access-ubuntu-server-running-in-virtualbox-from-outside).

Next, I tried to access it from outside my network. I used my mobile phone for that(not WiFi ofcourse)

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

this gave me my outside IP. I tried to access it, but my browser couldn't connect. I noticed all my devices have the same outside IP.
Is it possible to access ubuntu server running in virtualbox from outside network or do I need to install it on a separate system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether the server is a real or a virtual machine, you will need to forward the appropriate port(s) across your LAN router, i.e. translate from the public IP you obtained from ifconfig.me to the server's private IP. You will need to refer to your router's documentation to see how to do that for your specific device.

If you wanted to use the VM in NAT mode, it should just require the additional step of forwarding the equivalent ports across that as well, i.e. from the host's real LAN IP to the VM guest's virtual LAN IP.