# I can't connect to Virtual Ubuntu Server from smartphone

Tags: networking, server, android, vmware

I'm developing a web app for my degree. Due to security reason I installed Ubuntu Server on VMware Workstation and, with IP that I found thanks to ifconfig command I can reach the app from desktop browser (the same PC Dekstop with VM Workstation).

However, I can't connect to IP from my smartphone Android (which is connected to the same home router). Any tips?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using bridged adaptor?

Comment: No, I set NAT as network connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the guest from outside the host you need to use "bridged adaptor". This will give an independent IP for the guest. Have a look at this useful post: [How do I access Ubuntu server running in VirtualBox from outside](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237461/how-do-i-access-ubuntu-server-running-in-virtualbox-from-outside)