# Dns problem ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, dns, webmin

I recently downloaded the ubuntu server 14.04 and I wanted to use the webmin, there's no error in installation and every thing sounds good.
I tried to put in browser https://name_server:10000 but nothing is showing. I tried to fix it with this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750502/unable-to-access-webmin-through-browser
I've tried nc -zvw 3 recserver 10000 (the recserver is the name of my server)
and this is what I find in browser :

' DNS address of server recserver isn't found. 
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN'

How can I fix it?
I haven't a good knowledge in ubuntu server and network.
Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Does it work when you try to access the server with its IP and webmin port?

Comment: I'm sorry for this stupid question but, how can I know the ip of the server? it's the same with the ip of my laptop?

Comment: I tried ip addr show to know it and I tried it in the browser but there's nothing

Comment: This is a large area to cover, where there could be many reasons why you're not getting the page to load.  The initial error message you're getting simply could indicate an unresolvable host on your network.  It may not be webmin not running or experiencing any error.  When you mention your laptop, is that where you install webmin?

Comment: Yes, I have the ubuntu server in virtual box.

Comment: This error came out when I did the command of netcat. There's no DNS address for recserver, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This is a good place to start.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/237461/how-do-i-access-ubuntu-server-running-in-virtualbox-from-outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the webmin working, I must have an Ip address for my server. When I try "ip addr show" I don't find it.
The best video that I found to show how to have an ip adress is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ykt3MeNwORQ