# (VirtualBox) Connect to Ubuntu Guest webbrowser

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2

I've just updated my apache2 on my guest system, but I still cannot access the guest through my host webbrowser.

I'm already using a host-only adapter and I can ping the guest without problems.

These are the solutions I tried without success:

[How can I access Apache (on VirtualBox guest) from host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52147/how-can-i-access-apache-on-virtualbox-guest-from-host)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108878/how-to-connect-to-a-guest-vm-from-the-host-system

Whenever I type in the IP of my guest, I get the message that the DNS address was not found.

Comment: You've tried this solution? http://askubuntu.com/questions/237461/how-do-i-access-ubuntu-server-running-in-virtualbox-from-outside

Comment: Yeah both host-only and bridged do not work for me @Rexford