# Remote access for Ubuntu server from VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, virtualbox

I'm trying to give access of my virtualbox guest system to global. I've seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237461/how-do-i-access-ubuntu-server-running-in-virtualbox-from-outside?rq=1) and done changes to Network settings, so them look like this now

[image]

After configuration, from that answer I have to

> To be able to access the server from your mobile (i.e. from outside of
>   your LAN), after configuring the networking you additionally will need
>   to set up port forwarding on your DSL modem.

How can I do this? I found several ways to do port forwarding, but I'm really new to this topic and don't quite understand what I have to do.

In the very end I want to give access to my virtualbox machine from remote, not local network.

Comment: Look up the manual for your router and search for the User manual, should give you step by step how to add a port forward, what service are you using? SSH?

Comment: yes, SSH. I can't get it - for different routers, I have to do a different setup? there is no way to do this on the system level?

Comment: Yes, of course port forwarding depends on the router and different routers have different settings. No, it can't be done from the clients. If you're dealing with remote access, not knowing this things is not an option.

Comment: It is also imperative that you harden your server. https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1604-lts-server-part-1-basics